# Cant make case-insensitive regular expression in PHP

Tags: php

I cant make a working regexp in php. I'm using `i` flag at regexp pattern, but it doesnt make a effect on result of my script:

```
$page = "Test";
$page1 = "test";
var_dump(preg_match("#^test#i", $page));
// int(0)
var_dump(preg_match("#^test#i", $page1));
// int(1)
```

I really cant realize, where i made a mistake, please help.

Comment: Both of those return 1 for me. For conventions you should use `/` instead of `#`

Comment: Thanks, using `/` was helpful. But now, when i try search 2 russian words, with the same scheme, it again returns int(0). For example, searching `/один два/i` in `Один Два` string returns int(0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check case-sensitive you have to remove the `i`:

```
$page = "Test";
$page1 = "test";
var_dump(preg_match("/^test/", $page));  // int(0)
var_dump(preg_match("/^test/", $page1)); // int(1)
```

If you want to check case-**i**nsensitive you have to add the `i`:

```
$page = "Test";
$page1 = "test";
var_dump(preg_match("/^test/i", $page));  // int(1)
var_dump(preg_match("/^test/i", $page1)); // int(1)
```

**demo:** http://ideone.com/Ab9nrs

I tried your code on 3v4l.org and it looks good on the most PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/5UeCu

Answer (score 0):

That code returns "int(1)" for both lines, in PHP 7.1.2 and 5.3.4.  Either you are running a PHP version where preg_match has a bug, or you have an invisible control character in one of your two preg_match expressions, and you simply cannot see it.

Comment: I recommend you 3v4l.org. There you can test code on many versions of PHP: https://3v4l.org/5UeCu