# Check username with optional patterns

Tags: php, regex

I want to check usernames in PHP which satisfy the following conditions:

- Must start with alphabets (*one or more*)
- Can contain letters (*optional, any length*), numbers (*optional, any length*) or underscore (*optional, only one*)
- Must end with an alphanumeric character
- Alphabets are case insensitive

How can I match this pattern using `preg_match()` function?

Here is the pattern that I tried. But I don't know how to set optional quantifiers:

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9]$
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt on your own to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. To test and learn more about regex, you can use https://regex101.com/

Comment: I added the patterns I tried. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: _"But I don't know how to set optional modifiers"_ You already did. The `[a-z0-9_]*` part is optional. What _exactly_ is the problem? Just one side note: unless you use the `i` flag, each `a-z` instance needs to be `a-zA-Z` (for case-insensitivity).

Comment: Yes, it's working fine now. But didn't work first time IDK why. I am not good at regex, so I thought I have error in my pattern. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: I didn't notice that you don't want more than one underscore. If that's the case, you may use `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*_?[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]$`. Or a shorter version: `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*_?[a-z0-9]+$`. Both are equivalent. I'd use the latter but I included the former to help you understand the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern *almost* works but it will allow more than one underscore. To prevent that, you may use the following pattern:

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*_?[a-z0-9]+$
```

**Details:**

```
^          # Beginning of the string.
[a-z]      # Matches exactly one English letter.
[a-z0-9]*  # Matches zero or more English alphanumeric character (i.e., letter or digit).
_?         # Matches zero or one underscore characters.
[a-z0-9]+  # Matches one or more English alphanumeric characters.
$          # End of the string.
```

Note that in order to make this case-insensitive, you either need to use the `i` modifier (i.e., `/pattern/i`) or use `a-zA-Z` instead of just `a-z` in all the character classes.

---

### References:

- [Regular Expression Quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).
- [Case insensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43856679/8967612).